# how to calculate mode using frequency table in C++

Tags: c++, statistics

My assignment is to print the mode (the most frequent value) of the data and I've written the code that tells which value has occurred how many times but it also displays some random numbers after my output i can't seem to figure out why

```cpp
//Calculating and displaying mode

   for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        count = 1;
        for(j=i+1; j<6; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                    {
                        count++;
                        arr_freq[j] = 0;
                    }
            }
        if(arr_freq[i] != 0)
            arr_freq[i] = count;
    }
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            if(arr_freq[i] != 0)
                cout<<arr[i]<<"      "<<arr_freq[i]<<endl;
        }
```

i expect the program to print the most frequent value(mode) but this is what i get

```cpp
3      1
6      1
7      1
8.9      3
5.88413e-39      5.88232e-39
0      5.88232e-39
5.88232e-39      4.96894e-09
0      3.88412e-41
0      9.19956e-38
0      4.34276e-41
0      1.4013e-45
4.96894e-09      5.88131e-39
9.19956e-38      9.26428e-26
4.34276e-41      9.18712e-18
0      5.88232e-39
5.88131e-39      9.19956e-38
0      4.34276e-41
5.88232e-39      -234877
0      -4.92527e+10
9.19956e-38      4.5936e+19
4.34276e-41      -1.71458e+36
4.5936e+19      5.88402e-39
0      9.19956e-38
0      4.34276e-41
0      1.4013e-45
```

i want it to print that "the mode is: (the most frequent value)"

Comment: So basically you have an array of integers and you want to print the frequency of each element in the array along with the mode?

Comment: Could you provide your array?

Comment: A way would be to sort your array, and then look for the longest sequence of identical numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question, which has been asked more often on SO.

To count the frequency for an element in an array. The standard approach is to use a `std::map`, store the values of the array in there and increment the corresponding slot for each related value.

The maximum frequency can be found with a STL-std-algorithm `std::max_element`.

So essentially we need 2 statements to answer the question.

Please see one of many solution proposals below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> arr{1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7};

int main()
{
    // Here we will store the frequency for each element 
    std::map<int, size_t> frequency;

    // Make reading easier
    using pair_t = decltype(frequency)::value_type;

    // Count frequency
    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [&frequency](int& i){ frequency[i]++; });

    // Output highes frequency of array value
    std::cout << "\nMax:  " << std::max_element(frequency.begin(), frequency.end(), []
        (const pair_t& p1, const pair_t& p2){ return p1.second < p2.second;})->first << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```